# How to horizontally center a <select> element

Tags: css

I am having the following code:

```
<div>
    <select>...</select>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

What is the cleanest way to center my dropdown `<select>` but keep the `<p>` left aligned?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want?

Comment: Another way is to use `text-align:center` http://jsbin.com/vaqenusaxa/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<select>` is inline level element, to center it you could set the container element to `text-align:center`.

By applying the rule the above, text that inside `<p>` will also get centered, because it inherits it from the parent, you could reset it with `text-align:left`. The `<p>` itself is still left aligned actually, because it's block level element.

```css
select, p {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
div {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select>...</select>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

Or, you could change `<select>` from inline to block level `display:block` or `table` etc., and then center it with `margin:auto` on itself.

```css
select, p {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
select {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select>...</select>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3gnvhxth/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do. Make you select display block and give it auto margins.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a85tdcht/)

```
div select {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```